Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/component/Heading.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "{" (27:7)
Current i am trying to returning a
object look like {text,object} from and jsx
but i am keep getting this error
Cannot assign to read only property 'message' of object 'SyntaxError: /src/component/Heading.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "{" (27:7)
i tried this following code:-
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

function Head() {
  const date = new Date();
  const currentTime = date.getHours();

  let greeting;

  const customStyle = {
    color: "",
  };

  if (currentTime < 12) {
    greeting = "Good Morning";
    customStyle.color = "red";
  } else if (currentTime < 18) {
    greeting = "Good Afternoon";
    customStyle.color = "green";
  } else {
    greeting = "Good Night";
    customStyle.color = "blue";
  }
  return {greeting,customStyle};
}

export Head;


A simple typo / syntax issue - export { Head } or export default Head are valid
